# My Enum values not displaying Properly asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have enums in my model and it is not displaying assigned values in Display Name property in the view properly but it is displaying value "AB"

```
[display(Name) ="Value Assigned"]= AB
```

"value assigned" string. What should i do change my enum model or views??

Comment: Which version of MVC?

Comment: Can you share the razor code you are using to display the field?

Comment: MVC 5.  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Industry) Industry is my enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this Editor template code in /Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates Folder,Create the folder if it is not already present.

```
@model Enum

@* To display enum value in the view as it is givn by the data annotation Display[] method*@

@if (EnumHelper.IsValidForEnumHelper(ViewData.ModelMetadata))
{
    // Display Enum using same names (from [Display] attributes) as in editors
    string displayName = null;
    foreach (SelectListItem item in EnumHelper.GetSelectList(ViewData.ModelMetadata, (Enum)Model))
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            displayName = item.Text ?? item.Value;
        }
    }

    // Handle the unexpected case that nothing is selected
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName))
    {
        if (Model == null)
        {
            displayName = String.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            displayName = Model.ToString();
        }
    }

    @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => displayName)
}
else
{
    // This Enum type is not supported.  Fall back to the text.
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model)
}
```

No other changes are required hopefully.this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget using `jUIHint("Enum")` in the enum property of your model.

Additional Resouce: [codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/757357/ASP-NET-MVC-apply-templates-to-enum-properties)

Comment: can you add more description to the link?